# Multiple timer thread with single Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, datagridview, timer, visual-studio-2017

I am using VB.NET with Visual Studio 2017.

I am testing a form which has a datagridview. That grid is being populated with initial trading symbols. After loading symbols, I need to press Start button, which starts a timer1 to look for latest price of that symbol from exchange and start timer2. Timer2 will look for certain conditions of price, if met, will place an order to exchange and again look for another loop. While this is happening, timer1 is also running at 2 seconds interval to get latest trading price.

I am using two different `BackgroundWorker` for each timer to do these two tasks with grid.

This works almost fine, but sometimes, both or one of timers gets disabled.

I am looking for another good and best approach to this as far as code, design and architechure is concerned. If anyone can help.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Me.Timer1.Stop()

    Try
        With Me.DataGridView4
            For RowIndex = 0 To .RowCount - 1
                With .Rows(RowIndex)
                    'CODE FOR CHECKING LTP OF SYMBOL
                End With
            Next
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.DoWork
    Me.Timer2.Stop()


    Try

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView4.Rows

            Dim TRDSYM As String = row.Cells(1).Value
            Dim orderid As String = row.Cells(6).Value
            Dim Ltp As Decimal = row.Cells(2).Value
            Dim EntryPrice As Decimal = Ltp

            'PLACING AN ORDER TO EXCHANGE BASED ON CONDITION
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'SetLog("Market Watch For Ltp Background Worker going on...", LogType.Others)
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    'SetLog("Order Placement Algorithm Background Worker going on...", LogType.Others)
    BackgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

        If Me.Timer2.Enabled = False Then
            Timer2.Enabled = True
            Me.Timer2.Start()
            Me.btnOrderplacementstatus.Text = "Order Placement Running..."
            Me.btnOrderplacementstatus.BackColor = Color.Green
        End If
        'SetLog("BackgroundWorker 2 Order Placement Thread started...", LogType.Others)
        Me.Timer1.Enabled = True
        Me.Timer1.Start()
        Me.btnMarketwatchstatus.Text = "Market Watch Running..."
        Me.btnMarketwatchstatus.BackColor = Color.Green

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker2.RunWorkerCompleted
    If Me.Timer2.Enabled = False Then
        Me.Timer2.Enabled = True
        Me.Timer2.Start()
        Me.btnOrderplacementstatus.Text = "Order Placement Running..."
        Me.btnOrderplacementstatus.BackColor = Color.Green
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If it doesn't work then your code is wrong.  If you don;t show us your code, which is basically a requirement of ANY question posted here at SO, then we can't help you.

Comment: Yes, adding the code

Comment: @jmcilhinney Code is added

Comment: Empty Try-Catches should be avoided.

Comment: @LarsTech, where do you find empty try catch?

Comment: Both DoWork methods have an empty Catch block.  You are ignoring all exceptions in the Try block.

Comment: Code works fine without any exception. My main curiosity is about making this efficient and beautiful code. Also how can I handle multiple process with single or multiple control in a better way

Comment: Not sure why you are using Timers since you turn them off right away.  BTW, `timer2.Enabled = True` and `timer2.Start()` is redundant.  Both do the same thing.  You should avoid interacting with GUI elements in the DoWork method, since GUI elements are on a different thread.  A "better way" would be working with the data source of the grid, like a DataTable or a List<Class>.

Comment: The first thing you should do is call `Stop` on the `Timer` in its own `Tick` event handler, NOT in the `DoWork` event handler of the `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: @LarsTech, I turn off timer so that background worker can fetch trade price from online server which takes time. I will not allow timer to start again while backgroundworker is in process. Any other option other than timer?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I will implement that also, any other way to make this code efficient and beautiful?